# Unit testing android listview scrolling using Roboelectric

Tags: unit-testing, scroll, robolectric

I have a method that attempts to programatically scroll to a position in a `ListView`.  The method has some conditionals so that its implementation differs slightly based on the Android SDK version the app is running on.

The functionality works fine on 3 android devices that I have tested on.  However, I have written a unit test using `junit` and [`Roboelectric`](http://robolectric.org/) that checks if the scrolling has made the the item at the target position visible.  The test fails.  When I debug, I notice that `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is 0 when running with `Roboelectric` (i.e., on the desktop vs. device or emulator).

I've tried ignoring the version and just using `ListView.smoothScrollToPosition()`, but the   `getFirstVisilePoition()` and `getLastVisiblePosition()` methods continue to return 0, even immediately after I call `smoothScrollToPosition(150)`.

Does anyone know if/how scrolling a listview can be tested using `Roboelectric`?

Any help would be appreciated - I can't seem to find any information on the topic.

Thanks,

Ana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using robolectric 1.1 or 1.2, here is the source for the AbsListView:
https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/shadows/ShadowAbsListView.java

It looks like all the scrolling functionality is it ShadowAdapterView:
https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/shadows/ShadowAdapterView.java

It doesn't look like `getFirstVisiblePoition()` or `getLastVisiblePosition()` are implemented.

I was able to get the smooth scroll position.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SmoothScroll {

    @Test
    public void testSmoothScroll() {
        Activity context = new Activity();
        ListView view = new ListView(context);

        view.smoothScrollToPosition(100);
        Assert.assertEquals(100, Robolectric.shadowOf(view).getSmoothScrolledPosition());
    }

}
```

You can get the smooth scrolled position.  Based on the height of the elements, you may be able to work out which ones are visible.